# didUpdateLocation not called first time run

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocation

location services within my app are not working the first time you run it. The second time, and any time after that though, it works fine. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways ||
    [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
NSLog(@"New Location. Lat: %f, Long: %f", latitude, longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `requestAlwaysAuthorization` runs asynchronously, so your code which checks authorization and calls `startUpdatingLocation` will execute before authorization has been given by the user. That's why it'll work the second time, because they gave the permission the first time. What you can do is implement `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` on the delegate and call `startUpdatingLocation` in there too (if status changed to authorized).

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestAlwaysAuthorization)

> When the current authorization status is
>   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined, this method runs asynchronously
>   and prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location
>   services